# How to convert Parametric equation to Cartesian form

Tags: vector, geometry, linear-algebra, parametric-equations

I need to convert a plane's equation from Parametric form to Cartesian form.
For example:

```
(1, 2, -1) + s(1, -2, 3) + t(1, 2, 3)
```

to:

```
ax+yb+cz+d=0
```

So basically, my question is: how do I find the a, b, c and d, and what's the logic behind the conversion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calculate normal vector to this plane :
`N = s x t` (vector product of two vectors belonging to plane)
Now you have coefficients a, b, c:

N = (a, b, c)

[image]

then substitute base point (in general - any point in the plane)
(1, 2, -1) to equation ax+yb+cz+d=0

```
a+2b-c+d=0
```

and find d

Comment: What is the intuition behind the coefficients of the Cartesian form being equal to the numbers of the normal vector?

Comment: @ThomasW the only useful vector in determining the orientation of a plane is the vector ortogonal to it (if you use vectors parallel to it, you need 2)